# Javafx how to load button animation then execute method

Tags: java, animation, javafx

I need help to load first the animation of the button then execute the onAction method because when I click the button, the animation of the button is delayed... How to fix it?

here is the sample code:

```
public void viewStage(ActionEvent event) {
try {
  FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("Stage.fxml"));
  Parent root1 = (Parent) fxmlLoader.load();
  Stage stage = new Stage();
  stage.getIcons().add(new Image("/img/Stage.png"));
  stage.setTitle("New Stage");
  stage.setScene(new Scene(root1));
  stage.show();

} catch (Exception e){
  System.out.println(e);
}
```

}

Comment: Where is the code?

Comment: The animation of the button when click was delayed. I want a smooth animation of the button when it tick/click.

Comment: Perhaps load the Image when the application starts up and access it when needed.

Comment: There is code in the question, but you posted code that's probably not needed to identify/reproduce the issue and left out the parts of the code where the thing you're asking about is implemented (the animation)...